# While mousedown and mousemove get coordinates of the mouse

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery that does when the user is clicking the slider get the coordinates but when he lifts up the mouse the function still runs

```
$("slider").mousedown(function(){
    $(this).mousemove(function(e){
       console.log(e.clientX);
    });
};
```

But when the users lift up the mouse the code still runs and still logs the coordinates.

Comment: Got a demo? Is it running on mouseup or mousemove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this:

```
$("slider").mousedown(function(){
    $(this).mousemove(function(e){
       console.log(e.clientX);
    });
};
$("slider").mouseup(function(){
    $(this).unbind("mousemove");
});
```

Comment: Damn, you beat me to it! :)

Comment: sorry. next time it's yours ;)

Comment: Yeah but with `mouseout` works until client gets the mouse off the object it's better `mouseup`

Comment: @FedericoPiragua of course. see my edit. you need to register the mousedown again. and it's mouseup instead of mouseout.

Answer (score 1):

Your mousedown function changes the mousemove function permanently. So you want to add something like this:

```
$("slider").mouseup(function(){
    $(this).unbind("mousemove")
};
```